# Usage of btTriangleIndexVertexArray

Tags: opengl, bulletphysics, bullet

I have managed to use this bullet physics struct, by it seems that the data it takes must be kept in memory.

Is there any reason for that? Am I using it right?

Answer (score 0):

Bullet Physics library prefer to passes pointers to objects back and forth. When you created your BT structure, and pass it to some other BT function, then it will not "copy" the data locally to itself. It will just grab a pointer to it, then act on it, then that's it. 
This is due to performance reasons: Copying such large data structures to local variables would be a waste of memory, and cpu cycles.

To answer the your last two questions:
Yes, I think you use it right. Keep your instantiated BT structures around until they are not needed anymore (e.g.: rigid body is removed from world, or application exit).